# Blank webpage generated using file_get_contents

Tags: php, html

This is index.php : http://pastebin.com/faGnYdT3

This is generate.php: http://pastebin.com/tRT3nLD3

I use:

```
$html = file_get_contents('index.php');
echo $html;
```

to display the content.

In index.php, I have used `<?php echo $variable?>` in every place to display details of the webpage, in generate.php it doesn't show the details and I have used POST Method to send all variables data to generate.php.
When download button is clicked on index.php, all variables are sent to generate.php and the webpage is displayed.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Screenshot: 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/45bc69c3e6014eb5be8be62c75ed607b.png

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you wanted to see or do. I couldn't analyze your problem

Comment: Please, take 5 minutes and read the following links to edit your question according to Stackoverflow standards: 
[Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It helps people who read your question, it helps you to get help.